# How to get view name in controller while navigating from view to controller in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have below view in my project,

```
PolicyScreen.cshtml
```

The above view has below control,

```
@Html.ActionLink("OK", "AccountScreen", "AccountUC", new { id= ViewBag.id})
```

Account controller looks like below,

```
[ActionName("AccountScreen")]
public ActionResult GetPolicyController(int id)
{
if (viewName='PolicyScreen')
{
//do validation
}
}
```

If I click OK, I am able to hit AccountUC controller and AccountScreen Action Name properly.
Now I need to know from which view I was navigated to AccountUC controller?

**The answer is PolicyScreen**, but I don't know how to get this view name in action method,any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why you need this, but you can do this by putting the view name in the action link parameters:

```
new { id = ViewBag.id, fromView = "PolicyScreen" }
```

And of course you'll need to alter your action method's signature:

```
public ActionResult AccountScreen(int id, string fromView)
```

If you want to get the view name automatically rather than hardcode it, see [Retrieve the current view name in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268763/retrieve-the-current-view-name-in-asp-net-mvc).

If you want the *action* name rather than the view name, see [Get current action and controller and use it as a variable in an Html.ActionLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779139/asp-net-mvc-get-current-action-and-controller-and-use-it-as-a-variable-in-an-h).

Comment: I am calling that action from many view, so only 1 parameter I need to pass, or else I have to change so many logic. Is there any other way to get view name? I have edited the question, kindly look at it.

Comment: _Why_ do you need to know from what view a link is clicked? Sounds like a problem that should be solved in another way. Though somewhat unreliable, you can try to [get the referrer URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471188/how-do-i-get-the-referrer-url-in-an-asp-net-mvc-action).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Html.ActionLink("OK", "AccountScreen", "AccountUC", 
            new { id= ViewBag.id , viewName="replaceCurrentViewNameHere"},null)
```

Make sure your action method has a parameter to accept the viewname we are sending

```
[ActionName("AccountScreen")]
public ActionResult GetPolicyController(int id,string viewName)
{
   if (viewName=='PolicyScreen')
   {
     //do validation
   }
}
```